# How do I bind an Interface to automapper using Ninject

Tags: ninject, automapper

I want to use DI whenever I call automapper so that I can uncouple some of my layers. Instead of calling automapper like this:

```
 public class MyController : Controller 
 {

     public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
     {
          var newModel= Mapper.Map<MyModel, NewModel>(model);
          return View(model);
      }
  }
```

I want to do this:

```
  public class MyController : Controller 
 {

     IMappingEngine _mappingEngine;

     public MyController(IMappingEngine mappingEngine)
     {   
        _mappingEngine = mappingEngine;
     }

     public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
     {
          var newModel= _mappingEngine.Map<MyModel, NewModel>(model);
          return View(model);
      }
  }
```

I am using Ninject as my IOC. How do I bind an interface to it though?

I also need to mention that I am using Profiles and already have:

```
var profileType = typeof(Profile);
        // Get an instance of each Profile in the executing assembly.
        var profiles = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(t => profileType.IsAssignableFrom(t)
                && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
            .Select(Activator.CreateInstance)
            .Cast<Profile>();

        // Initialize AutoMapper with each instance of the profiles found.
        Mapper.Initialize(a => profiles.ForEach(a.AddProfile));
```

I know that the step I am missing involves binding to the kernal:

```
kernel.Bind<IMappingEngine>.To<>(); //I do not know what
//to bind it to here so that when I call IMappingEngine;
//It will trigger my maps from my automapper profiles.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't seem to find `IMappingService` in the AutoMapper repository (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/search?q=IMappingService). However, there is a [`IMappingEngine`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/develop/src/AutoMapper/IMappingEngine.cs).

All you've got to do is

```
IBindingRoot.Bind<IMappingEngine>().ToMethod(x => Mapper.Engine);
```

or

```
IBindingRoot.Bind<IMappingEngine>().To<MappingEngine>();
IBindingRoot.Bind<IConfigurationProvider>().ToMethod(x => Mapper.Engine.ConfigurationProvider);
```

and you're good to go.

Remember, however, that the first access to `Mapper.Engine` or `Mapper.ConfigurationProvider` will initialize AutoMapper.

So without the binding, AutoMapper get's initialized the first time you do something like `Mapper.Map<,>`. With the binding it will get initialized the first time an object is constructed which gets `IMappingEngine` injected.

If you want to retain the previous initialization behavior there are a few choices:.

- a)  Instead of injecting `IMappingEngine` inject `Lazy<IMappingEngine>` instead (i think this requires the ninject.extensions.factory extension)
- b) bind `IMappingEngine` to a proxy (without target). The proxy should access the `Mapper.Engine` only when `.Intercept(...)`ing a method. Also it should forward the method calls.
- c) write your own `LazyInitializedMappingEngine : IMappingEngine` implementation which does nothing than forward every method to `Mapper.Engine`.

i would probably go with c), the others are too much work. c) will require code adaption whenever the interface of `IMappingEngine` changes. b) would not but is more complicated and slower. a) is bleeding through to all consumers of the interface and easily to get wrong once in a while, breaking stuff and a bit hard to trace back, so i would refrain from it, too.

---

c):

```
public class LazyInitializedMappingEngine : IMappingEngine
{
    public IConfigurationProvider ConfigurationProvider { get { return Mapper.Engine.ConfigurationProvider; } }

    public TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<TDestination>(source);
    }

    public TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source, Action<IMappingOperationOptions> opts)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<TDestination>(source, opts);
    }

    public TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(source);
    }

    //... and so on ...
}

kernel.Bind<IMappingEngine>().To<LazyInitializedMappingEngine>();
```

Comment: I realize I am late in asking about this but I was laid off from the job that I was at when I asked this. Could you give an example of Option C. I am not sure what you mean by "forward" to mapper.Engine

Comment: @Robert, i'm sorry to hear that. Hope you'll get a new job - a good one - soon! I'll post the example.